# Use of as.POSIXct on missing seconds

Tags: r, datetime

Sample dataset

```
df <- data.frame (dt1 = c("31.07.2022 23:57:06", "01.08.2022 00:02", "01.08.2022 00:07"), 
                  factor = c(21.59,21.75,21.375))
```

Tworzę kolumnę z datą i czasem

```
df <- df %>% mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(dt1, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

I get the following result:

```
                  dt1 factor                  DT
1 31.07.2022 23:57:06 21.590 2022-07-31 23:57:06
2    01.08.2022 00:02 21.750                <NA>
3    01.08.2022 00:07 21.375                <NA>
```

I would like the end result to be as follows

```
                  dt1 factor                  DT
1 31.07.2022 23:57:06 21.590 2022-07-31 23:57:06
2    01.08.2022 00:02 21.750 01.08.2022 00:02:00
3    01.08.2022 00:07 21.375 01.08.2022 00:07:00
```

I don't want to waste the information I have, so the deletion of seconds solution is not good

```
df <- df %>% mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(dt1, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
```

```
                  dt1 factor                  DT
1 31.07.2022 23:57:06 21.590 2022-07-31 23:57:00
2    01.08.2022 00:02 21.750 2022-08-01 00:02:00
3    01.08.2022 00:07 21.375 2022-08-01 00:07:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lubridate::dmy_hms` with `truncated = 1` to deal with incomplete dates:

```r
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(DT = dmy_hms(dt1, truncated = 1))
#                   dt1 factor                  DT
# 1 31.07.2022 23:57:06 21.590 2022-07-31 23:57:06
# 2    01.08.2022 00:02 21.750 2022-08-01 00:02:00
# 3    01.08.2022 00:07 21.375 2022-08-01 00:07:00
```

See the details on the `truncated` parameter:

> The most common type of irregularity in date-time data is the
> truncation due to rounding or unavailability of the time stamp. If the
> truncated parameter is non-zero, the ymd_hms() functions also check
> for truncated formats. For example, ymd_hms() with truncated = 3 will
> also parse incomplete dates like ⁠2012-06-01 12:23⁠,  ⁠2012-06-01 12⁠
> and 2012-06-01.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. I wanted to maintain the POSIXct object, but I corrected the code myself. I appreciate the help.